# Web API DELETE request not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, iis-6

My web.config below. Everything is fine on my local host, but after upload to the amazon server (IIS 6.1) "DELETE" request is not allow, all other verbs works as expect (including PUT).

my web.config

```
  ...
     <handlers>
          <remove name="WebDAV" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <

/handlers>
...
```

my angular controller

```
function deleteSlide (post)
     {
       post.$delete({ id: post.PostId }, function(){alert("deleted")},
       function(){alert("can't delete")}
    );  
 }
```

web api action for delete:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(post))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeletePost(int id)
        {
            Post post= await db.Posts.FindAsync(id);
            if (post== null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Post.Remove(post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(post);
        }
```

Comment: can you please add sample request for delete call ?

Comment: it is like http://localhost:65324/api/post

Comment: more likely it should be like  localhost:65324/api/post?id=1 can you please add your code for web api controller method delete ?

Comment: yes I've checked with chrome rest console and seems to be fine by my angular controller still can't delete post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it that case double check if post.PostId is not null because the rest of your code seems fine.

```
function deleteSlide (post)
     {
       console.log("Postid=" + post.PostId) //<- can't be null
       post.$delete({ id: post.PostId }, function(){alert("deleted")},
       function(){alert("can't delete")}
    );  
 }
```

Comment: thank  you that was that instead  `post.PostId` should be `post.postId`

Answer (score 0):

Try also remove WebDavModule:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
...
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```